# TypeError: If class_mode="categorical", y_col column values must be type string, list or tuple

Tags: python, keras

In [keras documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), it is mentioned that `"categorical": 2D numpy array of one-hot encoded labels. Supports multi-label output.` but in my case, it does not support.

```
train_generator_1 = train_data_gen.flow_from_dataframe(annotation,
                                                      directory="data",
                                                      target_size=(img_shape,img_shape),
                                                      x_col="Left",
                                                      y_col=['N','D','G','C','A','H','M','O'],
                                                      class_mode='categorical',
                                                      shuffle=False,
                                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                                      seed=7)
```

The picture of labels is attached.
Error i am getting is `TypeError: If class_mode="categorical", y_col="['N', 'D', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'H', 'M', 'O']" column values must be type string, list or tuple.`

[image]

Comment: Check either y_col does contain any nan value or refer this link to match type of your data https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/9a836c25177e1be5940e1b2ab19fdb383225c32a/keras_preprocessing/image/dataframe_iterator.py#L201

Comment: no, they dont contain missing values

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple outputs, you'd have to choose class_mode as 'raw'. 
I found a great tutorial by Vijayabhaskar J here. https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/multi-label-image-classification-tutorial-with-keras-imagedatagenerator-cd541f8eaf24

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't want to switch to `raw` class_mode, so found a different solution that still uses `categorical` class_mode.

`flow_from_dataframe` gets weird when using multiple column names in y_col -- especially when using 'categorical' class_mode.  It's expecting the value of the column specified in y_col to be an array -- not for there to be an array of columns.  Change it to a single combined column that contains an array of each value, and you'll be golden:

```
y_cols = ['N','D','G','C','A','H','M','O']
dataframe['classes'] = dataframe[y_cols].apply(lambda x: x.tolist(), axis=1)

train_generator_1 = train_data_gen.flow_from_dataframe(annotation,
                                                      directory="data",
                                                      target_size=(img_shape,img_shape),
                                                      x_col="Left",
                                                      y_col="classes",
                                                      class_mode='categorical',
                                                      shuffle=False,
                                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                                      seed=7)
```